# How to simplify $\dfrac{(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}11^k) - m\%10}{10}\%10,\quad m\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

### How to simplify $\dfrac{(\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}11^k) - m\%10}{10}\%10,\quad m\in \mathbb{N}$ ?

where $\%$ means 'modulus operation', e.g. $47\%10=7$

p.s.
It involves modular operation with division operation, so I tried to use Fermat's theorem to simplify, but $\gcd(10,10)\neq 1$.

I wonder if the formula can be further simplified.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you tried writing m as $10A + c$ and simplifying from there?

Comment: The sequence seems to be periodic of period $50$: $0,1,3,6,0,5,1,8,6,6,6,7,9,2,6,1,7,4,2,2,2,3,5,8,2,7,3,0,8,8,8,9,1,4,8,3,9,6,4,4,4,5,7,0,4,9,5,2,0,0$

Comment: It seems so, I'm thinking that this might indicate that the formula has some kind of explicit expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hints:*

$\displaystyle
\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}11^k = \frac{11^m-1}{11-1}
$

$\displaystyle
11^m=(1+10)^m=1+\binom{m}{1}10+\binom{m}{2}10^2+10^3 a
$

Write $m=10q+r$. Then the expression is $\displaystyle\left(q+\binom{m}{2}\right)\%10$.

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A008954